# re-serialize? array

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array:

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [type] => jpg
        [name] => 25.jpg
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [type] => jpg
        [name] => 26.jpg
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [type] => jpg
        [name] => 27.jpg
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [type] => jpg
        [name] => 10.jpg
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [type] => jpg
        [name] => 11.jpg
    )
```

how i can change back the id to 0,1,2,3... etc?
instead of 2,3,8,13,14?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming they're still well-ordered, and assuming your array is named `$input`:

```
$result = array_values($input);
```

Should work.

Answer (score 8):

Try [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).